# How to get rid of xmlns namespace declaration from HTML output by a XSL?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am creating a HTML `<div>` from a xsl file but the created div has the xmlns namespace declarations as attributes.

This is the dialed down version of my XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
        xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"          xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
        xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"
        xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"         
version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="ab:cde">
        <div>
            <!-- some stuff here -->
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output div beight created is:

```
<div xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to get rid of these namespace declarations from my `div`?

Thnx in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute on the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element. In your case:

```
exclude-result-prefixes="w a r"
```